# Has anyone got ledger working within docker?

Tags: ledger, docker

I'm getting a strange error when trying to use a ledger from a docker container.

```
docker run --rm --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb:/dev/bus/usb -it tezos/tezos:zeronet_586d6c57_20190201220447 tezos-client -A my-node list connected ledgers
Warning:

                 This is NOT the Tezos Mainnet.

      The node you are connecting to claims to be running on the
                 Tezos Zeronet DEVELOPMENT NETWORK.
           Do NOT use your fundraiser keys on this network.
  Zeronet is a testing network, with free tokens and frequent resets.

Found a Tezos Wallet 1.5.0 (commit cb85201c) application running on Ledger Nano S at [0003:000a:00].
Fatal error:
  Not_found
```

Has anyone got this working or know what might be the problem?

Ledger running latest firmware with Tezos wallet app 1.5.0. The ledger also works fine when using Tezbox wallet.

The `my-node` is running on a different machine, don't know if/how that could be relevant ‍♂️

Comment: As a followup I can confirm that the ledgerblue install process works from inside the container  Still getting same Fatal Error, also with `tezos-signer list connected ledgers` . Also tried a rebuild of tezos inside the container - no such luck 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Ref. https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/475

Apparently the **USER** env variabled needs to be set for it to work  It is not set by default in official docker images.

I'm reaching out to have them set it

Comment: Precisely, set "ENV USER=tezos" in dockerfile or use "docker run... -e USER='tezos' ...".

Comment: Also the additional volumes are not needed when you run the container with the "--privileged" option. Full working command for reference: 
"docker run --rm --privileged --name tzdocker -it -v /tzdata:/var/run/tezos/node tezos/tezos:mainnet tezos-node ..."
# check ledger attachment:
"docker exec -it tzdocker tezos-client -A localhost list connected ledgers"