# Baking with remote signer compatible with --require-authentication?

Tags: baking

For client ops, using a remote signer with `--require-authentication` requires manually entering the client key's decryption password.

It's not documented anywhere -- is this incompatible with baking? There's no way that I'm aware of to decrypt the client key when setting up baking and I assume authentication isn't bypassed for baking.

Thanks

Comment: On alphanet it works without entering the password for the authentication key, but in mainnet it ask for password on terminal, but due to absence of any terminal to enter the password it fails. I am also looking out for an answer to this.

Comment: Although you can bypass the authentication method by not using --require-authentication flag in tezos-signer command. Make sure to restrict access to your server and port using firewall though if you bypass the authentication method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As touched on in comments, the most correct answer to this is:

No, you cannot use `--require-authentication` with a signer for baking. There's no TTY present and you cannot decrypt the authentication key when an endorsement / baking operation needs to run.

Best practice here is to use an encrypted tunnel between the signer and the baker and for the signer to not be directly accessible to the network.

Answer (score 3):

On tezos mainnet, you cannot generate your key in unencrypted form. So you have to enter the password to decrypt the key.

Solution is to import an unencrypted key and then use is to authenticate any communication with remote-signer.
I used [tezbox wallet](https://tezbox.com) to generate unencrypted keys and then copy the private key and imported to my server using below command.

```
./mainnet.sh client import secret key auth-alias unencrypted:edskxxxxxxxxxxxxxTnZR
```

Comment: isn't it intrinsically *unsafe* to generate an unencrypted unencrypted private keys and copy this around for another server ?

Comment: Yes it is unsafe if you are using this key as baking key. But here the only purpose for this is to be used as authentication key, but obviously precautions need to be taken while copying your private key to the server. If you don't want to copy the private key and want to generate the private key on the server only you can use https://github.com/TezTech/eztz

Comment: how abt simply using ledger ?

Comment: Yes using ledger would be most secure way but i don't have any experience with ledger. Any documentation for this would be really helpful.

Comment: you can search here on TSE there are answers to get you started. Eg: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/395/118 and https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/477/118 . If this is not sufficient then feel free to ask a new question!

Comment: Definetly he shouldn't use unencrypted keys - that's a really terrible idea.

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to have unencrypted keys on a network-accessible machine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to have more security than both answers (as of today) https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/607/29 (Answer A) and https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/598/29 (Answer B) suggest.

If the signer

- only accepts magic bytes 0x01,0x02,
- and the signer is firewalled to only accept request from the baker's IP
- and the tunnel is encrypted (preferably),

it is ok to leave the unencrypted signer auth key in the baker. You get the convenience of answer B, but with the added security of using a signer auth key (answer A). It doesn't protect you against every possibility (it is not possible at this time to pass the password to the baker/endorser, AFAIK even using [one of these methods](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391040/is-there-a-typical-way-to-pass-a-password-to-a-systemd-unit-file)), but by having an unencrypted signer auth key you are still avoiding some potential risks . For example, if a rogue machine obtains your IP (say you release the IP by accident, or your host misroutes your IP) the attacker still won't be able to even simply double bake/endorse.

Some might say it is more work for little gain, but I am a bit paranoid and don't like to take the easier route.

Bottom line, `--require-authentication` is not a substitute for other precautions.