# Why my endorser did not endorse the block 316956?

Tags: baker, endorser, remote-signer, missed-endorsement

I have setup my node, baker and endorser using docker image on one server and setup a remote signer on another server.

Now when it comes to my chance of endorsing it missed and i did not see any such logs in my endorser logs except and error for my auth key password (mentioned below) which has nothing to do with my baking account as it was used as authorized key to connect with remote-signer only.

> [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Current head: BLb3yr9bGYu9
>   (timestamp: 2019-02-17T07:59:10Z, validation: 2019-02-17T07:59:59Z)
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Bootstrapped.
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Enter password for encrypted key
>   "auth": Fatal error: [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ENOTTY, "tcgetattr", "")
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Waiting for the node to
>   synchronize with the network... [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   Disclaimer: [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   The  Tezos  network 
>   is  a  new  blockchain technology. [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   Users are  solely responsible  for any risks associated
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   with usage of the Tezos network.
>   Users should do their [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   own 
>   research to determine  if Tezos is the appropriate
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   platform for their needs and
>   should apply judgement and [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   care
>   in their network interactions. [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Current head: BLAJbqV8Bxn1
>   (timestamp: 2019-02-17T08:00:10Z, validation: 2019-02-17T08:01:02Z)
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Bootstrapped.
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Enter password for encrypted key
>   "auth": Fatal error: [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ENOTTY, "tcgetattr", "")
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Waiting for the node to
>   synchronize with the network... [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   Disclaimer: [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   The  Tezos  network 
>   is  a  new  blockchain technology. [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   Users are  solely responsible  for any risks associated
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   with usage of the Tezos network.
>   Users should do their [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   own 
>   research to determine  if Tezos is the appropriate
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   platform for their needs and
>   should apply judgement and [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   care
>   in their network interactions. [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Current head: BLMtVK6RWXSk
>   (timestamp: 2019-02-17T08:01:10Z, validation: 2019-02-17T08:02:04Z)
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Bootstrapped.
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Enter password for encrypted key
>   "auth": Fatal error: [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ENOTTY, "tcgetattr", "")
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m Waiting for the node to
>   synchronize with the network... [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   Disclaimer: [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   The  Tezos  network 
>   is  a  new  blockchain technology. [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m
>   Users are  solely responsible  for any risks associated
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   with usage of the Tezos network.
>   Users should do their [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   own 
>   research to determine  if Tezos is the appropriate
>   [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   platform for their needs and
>   should apply judgement and [[36mendorser-003-PsddFKi3_1  |[[0m   care
>   in their network interactions.

Block Timestamp was 2019-02-17T08:00:10Z

What could have gone wrong and where i can check it?

NOTE: One thing to notice here is i changed the server on which my baker was running after i got the endorsement rights because of some issues with server. When i registered the baker again it says no need to register the baker as it was already registered. Is this have something to do with my endorsing that i changed my node identity?

Comment: "it was used as authorized key to connect with remote-signer only" -- do you mean that you are not using this remote signer (which required this authentication) to sign endorsements, but some other key/signer?

Comment: Yes i imported the other key(used as baker) from remote-signer (baker key was generated on remote-signer) and "auth" key was generated on node and registered as authorized key on remote signer.  As it is mentioned here  https://tezos.gitlab.io/alphanet/introduction/various.html#secure-the-connection   "Note that this key is only used to authenticate the client to the signer and it is not used as a Tezos account."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error logs clearly suggest that the ENOTTY error for the "auth" key is your problem.

You cannot directly use an encrypted key to authenticate the docker daemons to a remote signer, because you cannot type the password in. (As FLF OCP notes, "the ENOTTY error is coming from an attempt to ask the key password on a terminal, but there is no such terminal").

Comment: Maybe you should edit your reply to explain that the ENOTTY error is coming from an attempt to ask the key password on a terminal, but there is no such terminal. To avoid that, the key must not be encrypted (empty password).

Comment: Unencrypted key could work, but mainnet doesn't let you create them... Empty password for encrypted key won't work, I think.

Comment: how to generate unencrypted key?

Comment: Check this for solution to this problem.  https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/451/baking-with-remote-signer-compatible-with-require-authentication

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Tom, the error in the logs actually was the issue. Endorser was trying to endorse for "auth" key also as it was present in public_keys and in docker containers, endorser and baker try to perform their operation for all the keys by default.

And since my "auth" key was encrypted, it was asking for password and due to absence of any password it threw exception and it kept doing that, due to which my endorser was never in healthy state to perform actual endorsement operations.

To avoid this problem use unencrypted keys for authentication. [Check here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/451/baking-with-remote-signer-compatible-with-require-authentication) for how to create unencrypted keys.

Comment: It is very dangerous to use unencrypted private keys for a baker’s operations. Best practice is to use ledger to protect keys.