# Can I connect a Ledger Nano S to a Tezos baking node and have the Nano S sign blocks and endorsements?

Tags: ledger, solo-baking

I've already got a solo baking server running, but I'm not so comfortable with leaving my private keys on the server.

Can I connect my Ledger Nano S to the baking server and have the Nano S sign blocks and endorsements? And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: I just heard it was possible. I'm looking for a guide - don't even know where to start.

Comment: "too broad"? Which part of my question is not clear?

Comment: you have been offered answers. what have you tried now ?

Comment: I have accepted a good answer to my question. I don't understand why my question have been closed. That's quite rude and does not help me understand how I could have asked it better.

Comment: The Title of your question is too broad. But the body includes a valid question "Can I connect a Ledger Nano S to a Tezos baking node and have the Nano S sign blocks and endorsements?" which would make for a better Title and then have the body describe your setup (e.g.OS, local vs vps, docker?).  As long as you search to make sure it's not a duplicate I think the question could be re-opened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an app specifically created for baking by Obsidian Systems.

You can install it through Ledger Live (you might still need to enable developer mode in Ledger Live). Instructions [here](https://medium.com/@tezosbaking/tezos-app-now-on-ledger-live-b6e74be5dfd3).

You can read more about the baking app and wallet app [here](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos).

Comment: One thing to note is that the baking app and the wallet app are separate for security reasons. Because you would need to keep the baking app running while baking, it does not allow signing transactions. And exiting the apps would require the ledger pin.

Answer (score 3):

You can now download both the Ledger Tezos Baker and Ledger Tezos wallet directly within Ledger Live, bypassing a lot of the CLI work necessary before this existed.